# VirtualBox, разрешение экрана гостевой ОС

Tags: virtualbox

Добрый день.Есть система kubuntu 13.04 в ней стоит virtualbox 4.2.10 из репозиториев. Монитор настроен на разрешение 1920х1080. Как гостевая система установлена win xp sp3, в ней установлены гостевые дополнения. При этом максимальное разрешение которое можно поставить в гостевой ОС 1280х960. Можно ли как то поднять разрешение до 1920х1080? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуй

> Host+G Auto-resize Guest Display

и

> Host+F Switch to Fullscreen

Host - Right Ctrl (default)

Comment: да, именно этой галочки и не хватало.

Comment: Да простит меня @mks, но "...и не хватало" НЕ разрешения экрана, а полноэкранного и/или подогнанного_под_размер_экрана_хоста режима...@ArcherGodson телепат?;)

Comment: @Zerglyn, я год в техподдержке работал, телепатия прокачена )

Comment: По моему опыту достаточно "Auto-resize Guest Display"...